# Equation of a line as a determinant equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been looking for an answer in the forums and Google but couldn't find one.

Given two different points in the plane, $(x_1,\,y_1)$ and $(x_2,\,y_2)$, we know that the equation of that line can be written as: $$y-y_1=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)$$It's possible to rewrite this expression as a determinant equation: $$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x & y \\ 
1 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 
1 & x_2 & y_2
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

I do know how to reach this last equation starting from the first one.

However, I've been asked how to derive the **determinant equation** of a line given its slope ($m$) and a point $(x_1,\,y_1)$.

I know the solution is: $$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x & y \\ 
1 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 
0 & 1 & m
\end{vmatrix}=0$$
But I'm not very sure how to reach that determinant. What I do know is that the equation can be written as: $$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$
How do I transform this algebraic equation to the above determinant equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take your previous formula and subtract the second line from the third.  Then divide the last line by $(x_2-x_1)\neq 0$ to obtain the final result.

Note that the determinant will not change, because the determinant is $0$.

**Edit**:

$$0=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x & y \\ 
1 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 
1 & x_2 & y_2
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & x & y \\ 
1 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 
0 & x_2-x_1 & y_2-y_1
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & x & y \\ 
1 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 
0 & \frac{x_2-x_1}{x_2-x_1} & \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: But that assumes I remember the first formula. Isn't there other way to approach the problem? With the only information that $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$

Comment: Sure there is a way, but why not use the previous result. The other way would be to simply backtrack from your final expression and see what you have to do in reverse order.

Comment: I mean, of course we can use the previous result. But I was hoping there was an automatic way to convert $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ to a determinant equation, like rearranging terms or something. So your best bet would be to calculate the first determinant, then substract the second line from the third and dividing by $(x_2-x_1)$?

Comment: You simply use row operations on the matrix to get the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the edit :D.

Answer (score 2):

These determinants can be interpreted as expressing linear dependence, but of vectors in a $3$-dimensional vector space containing your affine place as a plane not going through the origin. Concretely let $w,x,y$ be coordinates of that space, then your affine plan is the one given by $w=1$.

Now flipping your determinants (because I like to stack coordinates vertically), points with coordinates $\binom{x_1}{y_1}$, $\binom{x_2}{y_2}$ and $\binom{x}{y}$ are collinear whenever the corresponding vector (with an addition coordinate $w=1$) are coplanar (the plane cuts $w=1$ in a line), and this is expressed by
$$\left|\matrix{1&1&1\\x_1&x_2&x\\y_1&y_2&y}\right|=0.$$
Now if instead of two points you give a point and a true vector (the slope corresponds to a translation of your plane, with coordinates $\binom1m$) then that vector should get extra coordinate $0$ rather than $1$. The coplanarity condition then becomes 
$$\left|\matrix{1&0&1\\x_1&1&x\\y_1&m&y}\right|=0$$
which up to some minor transformations is what you wrote.